# Text not displaying from JSON in Swift

Tags: json, swift

```
 import UIKit

let cellid = "cell"

class Post {
    var videoName: String?
    var videoDescription: String?
}
class VideoFeedController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var posts = [Post]()
    var json: [Any]?
    var names: [String] = []
    var contacts: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



        let CatagoryMain = Post()
        CatagoryMain.videoDescription = "example text"
        CatagoryMain.videoName = "wewewewew"

        posts.append(CatagoryMain)

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        navigationItem.title  = "Main Video Feed"
        collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        collectionView?.register(VideoFeedCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellid)

        let urlString = "example url"

        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("failed")
            } else {
                do {

                    let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String:Any]
                    let currentVideo = parsedData["video"] as! [String:Any]


                    if let currentVideoTitle = currentVideo["title"] as? String {
                          print(currentVideoTitle)

                        // have text display instead of wewewew and example text 
                    }

                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error)
                }
            }

            }.resume()
    }
```

So for now it says example text for the video description and wewewewew for the video name and those display fine.I am trying to get the info from the json though so instead of example text it would have the description and instead of wewewewew it would have the video name I thought it would go like this

```
if let currentVideoTitle = currentVideo["title"] as? String {
                      print(currentVideoTitle)

                    CatagoryMain.videoDescription = "\(currentVideoTitle)"
                    CatagoryMain.videoName = "\(currentVideoTitle)"

        posts.append(CatagoryMain)
                }
```

however that was wrong and if I do that nothing shows on the screen besides the navigation bar and the title for the navigation bar. Thank you in advance if you can help! The actual title does show in the console by the way.

Comment: so is there any output from the line  `print(currentVideoTitle)`? and also can you post the `currentVideo` json? that would be great:)

Answer (score 0):

Like the comment I left above, we need more code to figure out the situation and help you out :) And your question is a little bit unclear.

> however that was wrong and if I do that nothing shows on the screen
>   besides the navigation bar and the title for the navigation bar.

You mean the `UICollectionView` is not loading the data? or the data are not loaded into `posts` array? is `collectionView` even init-ed?

Also, would like to have a look of the `parsedData` object. As you are using `collectionView` which means you want to display multiple cells. But your parsing codes do not look like you are parse an array of objects.(but only one object??)

Quick advice,
1. Print out the `posts.counts` to see if there are data?
2. If there is any data, add `collectionView.reloadData()` after you added data to `posts`.